# How to test all effect with redux-saga-test-plan. All effect do not match

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I have a generator that I want to cover with unit-test

```
export default function* gatawayFlow() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST, getGatewaysFlow),
    takeLatest(actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST, selectGatewayFlow),
  ]);
}
```

I wrote a simple test with redux-sag-test-plan

```
import {expectSaga, testSaga} from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import gatawayFlow, {getGatewaysFlow, selectGatewayFlow} from '../logic/sagas';
import * as actions from '../logic/actions';
import * as actionTypes from '../logic/actionTypes';
import {takeEvery, takeLatest} from '@redux-saga/core/effects';

// Unit-test
describe('Unit tests', () => {
  test('Test all effect', () => {
    const saga = testSaga(gatawayFlow);
    saga
        .next()
        .all({
          [actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST]: takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST, getGatewaysFlow),
          [actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST]: takeLatest(actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST, selectGatewayFlow)
        })
        .next()
        .isDone();
    // expect(gatawayFlow().next().value).toEqual(all([
    //   takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST, getGatewaysFlow),
    //   takeEvery(actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST, selectGatewayFlow),
    // ])); ---> THIS TEST WORKS CORRECT
  });
});
```

And my test didn't pass. I have this error in my terminal. Any ideas how I can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use [all([...effects]) - parallel effects](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#alleffects---parallel-effects) instead of a dictionary Object of the form `{label: effect, ...}`

`saga.ts`:

```
import { all, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export const actionTypes = {
  GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST: 'GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST',
  SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST: 'SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST',
};

export function* getGatewaysFlow() {}
export function* selectGatewayFlow() {}

export default function* gatawayFlow() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST, getGatewaysFlow),
    takeLatest(actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST, selectGatewayFlow),
  ]);
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { expectSaga, testSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import gatawayFlow, { actionTypes, getGatewaysFlow, selectGatewayFlow } from './saga';
import { takeEvery, takeLatest } from '@redux-saga/core/effects';

describe('Unit tests', () => {
  test('Test all effect', () => {
    const saga = testSaga(gatawayFlow);
    saga
      .next()
      .all([
        takeEvery(actionTypes.GET_GATEWAYS_REQUEST, getGatewaysFlow),
        takeLatest(actionTypes.SELECT_GATEWAY_REQUEST, selectGatewayFlow),
      ])
      .next()
      .isDone();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/69252089/saga.test.ts
  Unit tests
    ✓ Test all effect (2 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |      100 |      20 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts  |      75 |      100 |      20 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.553 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how did you run a coverage script for redux-saga-test-plan?
I tried to run this ```npm test -- --coverage``` but I see only files that I wrote with jest

Comment: @ElliZorro [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring) configuration ignore `node_modules`, you don't need to test third-party library. You should use  fully self-tested library